# Equivalent to the 5 Ws in English

Tags: translation, expressions

Is there an equivalent to the English, "who, what, when, where, why" method of inquiry?

Comment: what are you asking? and what has your research turned up so far?  do you know the japanese equivalents of these words? have you tried to look them up online like through [denshi jisho](https://jisho.org)? what exactly do you mean by “method of inquiry“ (as a native english speaker myself and someone who teaches math and science, i have no idea what you’re referring to.)

Answer (score 1):

5Ws is the same method worldwide. You can use 5W (read ご・ダブリュ - go daburyu).

In Japan though, seems to be more common to hear 5W1H (read ご・ダブリュ・いち・エイチ go daburyu ichi eichi).

Source: https://kotobank.jp/word/5W1H-179226

Comment: 5W1H obviously doesn't refer to the Japanese words directly. Is this a phrase that all Japanese would know or only those that have studied English?

Comment: Not all japanese would know this. It is commonly seen in literature related to business, projects, etc. The english requirement is not a must though for being able to understand it.